# Updating config on 2960s Stack by copying from FTP

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, stacking, cisco-2960

I'd like to upgrade a stack of Cisco 2960s switches with a new configuration, and I would like to know what is required to copy a pre-populated config.text file from an FTP server to the switch stack.

Is there anything special needed to accommodate a stack of 2960s?

Is the syntax correct:

```
# copy ftp://server/config.text system:running-config
# reload
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are reloading, you want to replace the startup configuration, not the running configuration. Otherwise, the device will start up with the old startup configuration, which is stored on `nvram:`.

Replacing the running configuration is always problematic, anyway. You end up merging what you have in the file with the currently running configuration, not completely replacing it.

Something like:

```
# copy ftp://server/config.text nvram:startup-config
# reload
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see what you mean there cheers. So I take it then that doing this to a stack of switches is the same as doing it to a single switch?

Comment: With a stack, you are configuring the master switch, which replicates the configuration to all the other switches in a stack.